# NPM bootstrap and others with visual studio code

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, browserify

Though I hate it, I chugged down most of the theory of modern web design.

Let's pretend I am doing a full stack website with no heavy machinery in the background (node, server side stuff etc) just old plain html/css/js.

Now I did a npm init in the folder where I'm developing the website.

I put in bootstrap along with jquery, popper and all its dependencies.

Now I want to include bootstrap in the page.

How?

Though I never saw browserify and webpack before, I've read they are useful for js only so you can "require('module')" in your javascript code but no use for css in the frontend (html files).

For those, I saw people suggesting to point to a folder and prepare grunt (javascript task runner) scripts to copy css in folders where you point at.

There is any way?

My conclusion is:
NPM/browserify/webpack = Useless rube goldberg machine until you start developing javascript/node in the background

Solution: Old CDN/Download local copy and link it in the code

What am I missing?

Comment: Gulp is my preferred build tool if you do want to do everything from scratch. But it still does require manual work.

Depending on your application you might want to look into using a front end framework like angular, or Vue.js, which generate all the webpack stuff for you and have loads of other benefits.

Comment: Asp.Net MVC at the moment, it does everything and more.